# JMeter - save response to file listener but also ignore result

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, api-testing, performance-testing, database

In JMeter, I am using a post processor running `prev.setIgnore()` within the setup thread group to ignore those requests.

Some of these requests are JDBC requests to select data out of the database and to save the data to a file (using the save responses to file listener).

As designed, the post processor is then stopping the output of data to the file. If I disable the post processor, then the files are setup just fine. But when it's enabled, then the files are not setup.

I don't want the response time (for the JDBC select operation) in my output report but I do want the data out of the database into a file. Is there a compromise here or do I need to just accept the data in the report if I want the files to be setup correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JMeter Test Elements execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) [listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) are being executed **after** post processors and your [`prev.setIgnore()` instruction](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setIgnore--) prevents passing the sample result to the listeners.

One of possible options is writing the response data into a file in the JSR223 Post Processor itself, the relevant code would be something like:

```
new File('/path/to/your/file.txt').text = prev.getResponseDataAsString()
prev.setIgnore()
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Yep that's sorted it - thanks!